# Collection property doesn't load from parent object, but loads when separately queried

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having an issue loading an Entity Framework collection property.

When I try to eager-load the collection via the parent object, the collection property remains null. However, when selecting the child collection property directly in a query - the correct child objects are returned.

Here's my code:

```
var odr = Db.Orders
                .Include(o => o.Items)
                .Where(x => x.ID == orderID)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var manualItems = Db.Orders
                       .Where(x => x.ID == orderID)
                       .Select(x => x.Items)
                       .ToList();
```

When this executes, `odr.Items` is null, but `manualItems` has the correct values!

Even more bizarre: I set a breakpoint on some of the property setters of the `OrderItem` class (the type of `odr.Items` and `manualItems`) - and found that Entity Framework *was* properly retrieving, creating, and populating the child `OrderItem` objects. It just wasn't setting the `odr.Items` property.

Here's the class and mappings, for reference:

**Order**

```
public class Order
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    <snip>

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Order Item**

```
public class OrderItem : IOrderItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OrderID { get; set; } //I set a breakpoint on the setter here, it was called each time

    public string ProductSku { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

**Order Mapping**

```
public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderMap() : base()
    {
        HasKey(m => m.ID);
        Property(m => m.ID).HasColumnName("id").HasMaxLength(50);

        <snip>

        HasMany(m => m.Items).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderID);

        ToTable("order_details");
    }
}
```

**Order Item Mapping**

```
public class OrderItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem>
{
    public OrderItemMap() : base()
    {
        HasKey(m => m.ID);
        Property(m => m.ID).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(m => m.OrderID).HasColumnName("order_id");
        Property(m => m.ProductSku).HasColumnName("product_sku");
        Property(m => m.ProductName).HasColumnName("product_name");
        ToTable("order_items");
    }
}
```

I'm using .NET 4.6 and Entity Framework 6.1.3

Comment: What database are you operating against? The mappings etc. look fine, and I use EntityTypeConfigs regularly myself. I've run this scenario using SQL Server Express and it works as intended, the Items are eager-loaded. My thoughts are this isn't SQL Server, based on the naming convention suggest PostgreSQL though afaik .Include() is implemented there too... If it is PostgreSQL or a different Db provider you might try moving the .Include *after* the .Where() clause??

Comment: I'm working with MS SQL. The weird part is other classes with collection properties have no issues - just the Order class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that heart of the issue lay in the fact that ID field on the `Order` is a string.

After the order was created, the ID was being changed to all lowercase somewhere in the code. As a result, the `OrderItem.OrderID` didn't *exactly* match `Order.ID` - the casing was different.

As to why

```
var odr = Db.Orders
            .Include(o => o.Items)
            .Where(x => x.ID == orderID)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

worked, but

```
var manualItems = Db.Orders
                   .Where(x => x.ID == orderID)
                   .Select(x => x.Items)
                   .ToList();
```

didn't - it could have been slight differences in the generated SQL queries that caused SQL server to ignore casing  in the latter case but not the former. It could also have been Entity Framework itself doing post-query validation of the two ID fields.

Comment: Ah, so the case of the Order ID stored in the order item was different to the Id of the order?  That is a bit of an odd one. I wouldn't come across something like that as I don't use String IDs, though I used the strings when trying to reproduce that issue. I'll have a play with that case behavior because that would be a good one to know. :) Curious, did you have a FK set up between the two tables?

Comment: That's the oddest thing - the FK's were set up but SQL allowed the change of the FK column to lowercase anyway. It might be that the casing doesn't matter in MS SQL but it does in entity framework